# Remove custom ItemDataRoles

Tags: python, pyqt

I have created some custom roles onto qtreewidgetitems.

eg.

```
CustomRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 100

...
my_tree_item.setData(0, CustomRole, True)
```

Are there any commands that I can use to remove these custom roles, eg. `CutomRole` in this case?
I am trying to make the tree item 'clean'...

Tried checking online but unable to find results detailing as such.

Comment: try it: `my_tree_item.setData(0, False, CustomRole)`

Comment: It returns `False` if I do it `my_tree_item.setData(0, CustomRole, False)`, but that means `CustomRole` still exists, I guess?

Comment: see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56517505/how-to-iterate-over-a-qtreeview-and-color-all-matched-cells

Comment: @dissidia No, it is not possible to remove a role. I think you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what is your main objective?

Comment: @dissidia The way to clear data for a specific role is: `my_tree_item.setData(index, None, CustomRole)`. And note the role is the *last* argument.

Comment: Thank you all. I think I have confused myself thinking that I can 'clear' it